# Apache RewriteRule for redirection

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

A just want to:

```
vhost1.xyz.com/name1/*
```

redirect to:

```
vhost2.xyz.com/name2/*
```

Example:

```
vhost1.xyz.com/name1/24ds21t31?kofs=oif.com
```

redirect to:

```
vhost2.xyz.com/name2/24ds21t31?kofs=oif.com
```

It will be always something like: /name1/some_number_&chars?name=url

I have tried this code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^vhost1.xyz.com/name1/$
RewriteRule . - [E=myUri:%1,E=myQuery:%2]
RewriteRule . http://vhost2.xyz.com/name2/%{ENV:myQuery} [R=301,L]
```

But it's makeing:

```
vhost1.xyz.com/name1/24ds21t31?kofs=oif.com
```

redirect to:

```
vhost2.xyz.com/name2/kofs=oif.com
```

so "24ds21t31?" part is missing and I need this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^vhost1.xyz.com/name1/(.+)$
RewriteRule . http://vhost2.xyz.com/name2/%1 [R=301,L]
```

EDIT: we need all chars... not only dot (i made a mistake as i'm tired).
so (.+) instead of (\.+)

EDIT2: with the host before? (vhost1.xyz.com in rewriteCond)
don't you have any alias or other rewrite cond before?
if name1 doesn't exist it is also a problem... ( and alias or creating an empty directory should be a solution )

Comment: Thanks for replay, unfortunately I'm getting: 404 with vhost1.xyz.com/name1/24ds21t31?kofs=oif.com in my browser...

Comment: Thanks, checked the edited version but it won't help - still the same. I think that there may be a problem that vhost1.xyz.com/name1/ doesn't exist in fact and it's throwing 404 before try to redirect? I'm not sure is it making much sense. Anyway with the code from the topic I'm not getting any 404, it's redirecting but not as I want to.

Comment: It's redirecting, I have just made different mistake. Thanks, I'm checking it further.

Comment: I have checked it and everything is working like it should. Once again - thank you very much.